# ProPresenter and PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

My church uses ProPresenter for our Sunday morning presntations.  Unfortunately, I get the ProPresenter decks from the minister and worship leader midway through the week and have no way to read them at home on my PC.  It would be easier if I could set things up and edit them (or at least have an idea of what's in the deck) before Sunday morning.

I know ProPresenter can import from PowerPoint, but can the import go the other way as well?  Is there a way to read ProPresenter files (`.prox`) *without* ProPresenter?

Comment: Google search tells me this software is popular among lots of Churches. Is there a reason why :-s

Comment: It's very easy to manage worship services because ProPresenter controls the background (video, static images, etc.) independently of the foreground (i.e. text) and audio (which can be none).  It allows you to easily have video overlaid with text that you can manually move through - it makes presentations a bit more lively.  It's also easier to teach to new team members than PowerPoint, Keynote, and other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerPoint cannot import presentaions from ProPresenter. You can, however, [download the ProPresenter 4 demo](http://www.renewedvision.com/pro_download.php) (Mac or Windows) to open and edit presentations.

Answer (score 0):

actually if you are the pro presenter person you can legally download the program as long as you don't use your copy at the same time the church is using theirs.  Basically you can't have it loading on multiple machines being used at the same time.

Comment: It's generally good practice when you provide this type of advice to cite a source.  Otherwise it can lead to people recommending all kinds of  stuff (unintentionally or on purpose), that isn't really legal.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can install it on multiple computers. You can edit the files on a demo program on your own computer and then play the file on the computer at the church. If you are interested in a link, like a previous poster suggested, here you go: http://www.worshiphousemedia.com/software/57013/propresenter-6-for-windows.